# How do I set up a server like this?

Tags: networking, server, remote-access

So I know this has been answered already, but I'm still not sure. What I want to do is, to have Ubuntu installed on my computer, and the have it set up so that I could go wherever, go onto a special website, log in, and access and control the very same Ubuntu installation.

So this is like a server, but instead the OS would be physically on my PC, and the website would only be for access from anywhere.

And also, if I did this, would I be using my home WiFi (what I am aiming to do) or the WiFi at whatever place I am if I opened a website on that "remote" OS?

And I know there are remote PC services and solutions, but I'd like to make my own as I will have it just like I want it, and I can be sure that it won't be blocked by a proxy or whatever.

NOTE: All I'm looking for is what I'd need to get and/or set up. You do not need to go into loads of detail. I am a pretty advanced user, so don't be scared to go technical either ;).

Answer (score 1):

## The network:

**Setup dynamic DNS (so you can access your PC from anywhere)**:

Use a free service called NoIP:

1. Register for account at [NoIP](http://noip.com/).
2. Setup a domain name at their website (this is free, but will give you such a web address: `your-preferred-name.noip.org`)
3. Setup their *Dynamic Update Client* using [their guide](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/). After that:

   1. Execute `sudo chown "$USER" /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf` so that you can run their service without root access
   2. Add the `noip2` command to your *Startup Applications*.

**Setup your router to allow outside connections:**

You need to forward ports. **This differs for *every* router**, so check [portforward.com](http://portforward.com) for guides on pretty much every router.

Exactly what ports to forward shall be discussed later.

---

## Remote control:

**Remote terminal access:**

1. Install the OpenSSH server: `sudo apt install openssh-server`
2. Start it:

   1. (Ubuntu older than 15.04) `sudo service sshd start`
   2. (Ubuntu 15.04 or newer) `sudo systemctl start sshd`

Connecting from Windows using the PuTTY app ([website](http://www.putty.org/)).

**Remote graphical access:**

Your options:

> *VNC*

This is bundled with Ubuntu, in an application called 'Desktop Sharing'.

Connect from Windows using TigerVNC View ([website](http://tigervnc.org/))

> *TeamViewer (Not open source)* ([website](http://www.teamviewer.com))

This isn't open source, but works very fast.

---

## Router setup: (continued)

**Ports to forward:**

- `22` for SSH
- `5800` and `5900` for VNC
- Nothing required for TeamViewer

Comment: Now you can make is a wiki site if you wish, added in the links and formatted it slightly.

Comment: This would be the best answer so far, however I am looking for something which would let me access my pc graphically anywhere I want without any downloads or sites which might be blocked... Would that be possible? A remote terminal is fine I guess, but remote graphical access would be GREAT. Is VNC the only solution?

Comment: You can take a look at Chrome Remote Desktop. VNC is pretty good. I've heard that NoMachine NX is very fast and secure, but unfortunately I've never got it to run. Besides, (this might be slower) you can even access graphical apps (but not the full graphical environment)  from PuTTY. Search for 'SSH X Forwarding'.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have anything really to do with Ubuntu, this is really a networking and VPN question.

To start if your machine is going to live at your house and never move, you will need to configure your home router/firewall to allow you to VPN into your network (from outside of it), once you are in, then you can SSH to the server, VNC, or any other product you can find to control the machine.

If your server is hosted outside of your house, then you will need to contact the hosting provider to see how they want you to VPN into their network.

As far as wireless is concerned, where ever you are you will have to figure out how to connect to the internet, where ever the machine you want to connect to is concerned, it needs to connect from where it is.

Based on your question, that is my best answer.